# Web Scraping CSS Selectors With Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to print only the high impact news from the given currency.  When I include the `worsedata == True` conditional in the `if` statement the code prints nothing.  When I only include the currency conditional in the `if` statement it prints all USD news regardless of impact strength.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.forexfactory.com/#closed")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find("table", class_="calendar__table")

worsedata = False

for row in table.find_all('tr', class_='calendar__row--grey'):  #finds all rows on forexfactory.com 

    currency = row.find("td", class_="currency")
    currency = currency.get_text(strip=True)

    for impact in row.select("tr.calendar__row calendar_row calendar__row--grey span.high:not(.revised)"):
        worsedata = True

    if currency == "USD" and worsedata == True:

        actual = row.find("td", class_="actual")
        actual = actual.get_text(strip=True)

        forecast = row.find("td", class_="forecast")
        forecast = forecast.get_text(strip=True)

        print(actual, forecast)
```

Comment: instead of r.text  use r.content, than you will be able to find table that u r looking for..

Comment: No, the function still returns nothing when I change r.text to content.

Comment: soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
      table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'calendar__table')
      print(table) # this will print nothing as it does not have any content

Comment: soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    table1 = soup1.find('table', class_ = 'calendar__table')
    print(table1)

Comment: there is no  class_ = 'calendar__row--grey' in the content of table1...

Comment: if possible can u elaborate what u  want to scrap ....

Comment: I want to scrap the currency of my choice (could differ every day) and the respective high impact news for the specified currency,  this includes the actual, forecast, and whether the news was worse or better than expected.  I have the code to gather all this data but cannot find a way to isolate the high impact news and only print that.